# Spinner itemClick shows force close in android

Tags: android

I have used 4 tabs.I want show tabbar in all activity so i used to call activity like this,

```
         Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setClass(DontAllow.this.getParent(),HomePage.class);
     View view = getLocalActivityManager()
                .startActivity("Review opportunities", intent
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
         setContentView(view);
```

I call activity like this,
1st activity-->2nd activity(spinner click)-->error

```
 Spinner country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner State = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ArrayAdapter Contries_array = new ArrayAdapter(DontAllow.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Countries);
        ArrayAdapter States_array = new ArrayAdapter(DontAllow.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,States);
        Contries_array.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        States_array.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        country.setAdapter(Contries_array);
        State.setAdapter(States_array);
```

please help me...how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use spinner in an activity under tab layout,context should be properly handled.

Use this lines to set ContextView of your activity instead of using setContextView(...); method:

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_xml, null);
this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

This solved my issue when I was facing the same problem. Hope it helps!